# Can't get rectangle to show up on the bottom of the image

Tags: c#, drawstring, graphic

I'm currently trying to draw a black rectangle over an image, but it just wont go to the bottom of the image. If I try to push it down, it just fills the image with the black rectangle.

Here's my code:

```
public void AddTextToImage(string LabelText, string CardNo)
{
BitMap LabelImage = new BitMap("C:\ImageLocation");
int32 y = Convert.toInt32(CardNo;
int32 x = LabelImage.Width;

Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(LabelText), Convert.ToInt32(CardNo, LabelImage.Width, 250);

\\Mainly been playing with the numbers, can't figure out the right coordinates though
graphic.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, LabelImage.Width), 0, -200, LabelImage.Width, y);

graphic.DrawString(LabelText, new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Point(0,y));

picImage.Image = LabelImage;

}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you posted code that compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `-200`. It will be outside the image

```
 graphic.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, LabelImage.Width), 0, 200, LabelImage.Width, y);
```